# Ubuntu 20.04 Graphic Glitches upon waking from suspend

Tags: drivers, suspend, gui, amd-graphics

Specs:
Ryzen R9 3900x
Radeon RX 5700XT
G.Skill 32GB DDR4 RAM

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I am having a strange issue. Whenever I wake my PC from suspend, the graphics begin to glitch constantly. There's screen tearing, flickering, etc. I spent 3 hours on it without suspending it and there were no graphical issues whatsoever. However, once I suspended it and woke it up, the graphical glitches began happening immediately. Do you guys have any clue what might be causing this?

Comment: same here, but unfortunately not always, so hard to reproduce, on Kubuntu 20.04. Maybe worth to add your graphic setup, mine is a NVIDIA 1660 Super using NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: same, on my NVIDIA 940MX